# Data Frame Filter Values

Tags: r

Suppose I have the next data frame.

```
table<-data.frame(group=c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40),plan=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),price=c(1,4,5,6,8,9,12,12,12,3,5,6,7,10,12,20,20,20,5,6,8,12,15,20,22,28,28))

   group plan price
1      0    1     1
2      5    1     4
3     10    1     5
4     15    1     6
5     20    1     8
6     25    1     9
7     30    1    12
8     35    1    12
9     40    1    12
10     0    2     3
11     5    2     5
12    10    2     6
13    15    2     7
14    20    2    10
15    25    2    12
16    30    2    20
17    35    2    20
18    40    2    20
```

How can I get the values from the table up to the maximum price, without duplicates.

So the result would be:

```
group plan price
1      0    1     1
2      5    1     4
3     10    1     5
4     15    1     6
5     20    1     8
6     25    1     9
7     30    1    12
10     0    2     3
11     5    2     5
12    10    2     6
13    15    2     7
14    20    2    10
15    25    2    12
16    30    2    20
```

Comment: All you're doing is `dplyr::group_by(table, plan, price) %>% dplyr::slice(1)`, nothing with "maximum price". Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @r2evans For this particular example it works. But let's say there are duplicate prices in each `plan` that are _not_ the maximum. Your code would not give the desired result. Although it's also not clear whether OP wants to keep duplicates that not the maximum or whether prices would ever be unsorted.

Comment: I think I was inferring too much, good point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

table %>%
  group_by(plan) %>%
  slice(1:which.max(price == max(price)))
```

`which.max` gives the index of the first occurrence of `price == max(price)`. Using that, I can `slice` the data.frame to only keep rows for each `plan` up to the maximum price.

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 22 x 3
# Groups:   plan [3]
   group  plan price
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     1     1
 2     5     1     4
 3    10     1     5
 4    15     1     6
 5    20     1     8
 6    25     1     9
 7    30     1    12
 8     0     2     3
 9     5     2     5
10    10     2     6
# ... with 12 more rows
```